# Baking normal map causes weird shading

Tags: shaders, normals, geometry, normal-map

why does shading look better when normals are inverted?
I baked the normal map of my sculpted rock onto the low poly mesh.

[image]

[image: Normal Map]

Best regards

EDIT: bevor baking I enabled Auto Smooth on both the meshes (low and high poly) to ensure no hard edges on the normal map.

Comment: Maybe your normal were inverted when you baked? Can you post a screenshot of your normal map?

Comment: No, I created the low poly cube from scratch, duplicated it and subdivided to sculpt on it. Normals weren't inverted.
The normal map has been attached to the original post (edited)

Comment: Your normal map is inverted. Basically, you should not see this cyan-looking color on flat surfaces. probably something you did wrong while baking. Can you upload your blend file and/or describe your baking process step by step?

Comment: 1. I created a simple cube and uv unwrapped it.
2. I duplicated the cube and named both "_low" and "_high" to organize.
3. Both meshes have the same material with the sahder setting of an image texture node and normal-map node, both plugged into the normal map by leaving the other inputs blank (basecolor, roughness, etc...)
4. made sure the low poly mesh has Auto Smooth enabled so that the corners aren highlighted when baking.
5. made the baking process in cycles

Comment: Do you have the Color Space for the normals texture map set to Non-Color (instead of sRGB)?

Comment: yes, changing it from non-color to rgb makes no difference

Comment: In the blend file you sent. The mesh's normals were inverted. When put back in place and baking again, the results where somewhat acceptable. I couldn't fix the smooth-flat problem tho.